# SQLite is nor creating tables, how to create this manually with custom classes?

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-6, .net-framework-version

I'm using .Net Framework 4.7, EF 6 and SQLite (System.Data.SQLite), and as I understand it, SQLite does not create tables automatically. But how to correctly create them manually so that .Net understands them and loads them correctly? As I understand it, I need to create a separate table for each class. But how can I tie them together if I have other custom classes in some classes? And if number of databases (DbSet) does not match number of classes (that is, there are classes that are not represented through DbSet, but where they are presented more than 1 time).

So, can you give me an example for Users and all custom classes that are used in it? I started creating these tables as you can see, but ran into these problems. Besides, as I understand it, there are strict naming rules, etc.

```
namespace MarketBotProject
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;

    public class ContextClass : DbContext
    {
        public ContextClass() : base("name=Model1")
        {
            Database.CreateIfNotExists();
            Database.Initialize(true);
            using(ContextClass CC = new ContextClass())
            {
                CC.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Categories' ('Id' INT PRIMARY KEY, 'Name64' TEXT, 'Parent64' TEXT, 'Price' DOUBLE)");
                CC.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'Goods' ('Id' INT PRIMARY KEY, 'CategoryId' INT, 'Text64' TEXT)");
                CC.SaveChanges();
            }
        }


        public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Item> Goods { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<BUser> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<PartnershipRequest> PartnershipRequests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Promocode> Promocodes { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<xPub> xPubs { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<HPayment> HPayments { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name64 { get; set; }
        public string Parent64 { get; set; } = null;
        public double Price { get; set; } = -1;
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string Text64 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BUserId { get; set; }
        public Item Product { get; set; } = new Item();
        public int Count { get; set; } = 1;
    }

    public class Balance
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BUserId { get; set; }
        public double Available { get; set; } = 0;
        public double Frozen { get; set; } = 0;
        public double Spent { get; set; } = 0;
    }

    public class BUser
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Promocode Promo { get; set; } = null;
        public List<Order> Cart { get; set; } = new List<Order>();
        public List<int> OrderIds { get; set; } = new List<int>();
        public Balance CommonBalance { get; set; } = new Balance();
        public Balance PartnerBalance { get; set; } = new Balance();
        public BTCAddress Address { get; set; } = null;
        public int Referrals { get; set; } = 0;
        public int Role { get; set; } = 0;
        public string RoleDescription64 { get; set; } = "";
        public string Page { get; set; } = "Default";
        public Category Cat { get; set; } = null;
    }

    public class PartnershipRequest
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BUserId { get; set; }
        public string Username64 { get; set; }
        public string Nickname64 { get; set; }
        public double Sum { get; set; }
        public string Address64 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Promocode
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Code64 { get; set; }
        public int OwnerId { get; set; }
        public bool Used { get; set; } = false;
    }
    
    public class xPub
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Key64 { get; set; }
        public List<BTCAddress> Addresses { get; set; } = new List<BTCAddress>();
    }

    public class BTCAddress
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public bool Blocked { get; set; } = false;
        public DateTime Assigned { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public double StartedBalance { get; set; }
    }

    public class HPayment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BUserId { get; set; }
        public string Username64 { get; set; }
        public string Nickname64 { get; set; }
        public double BTC { get; set; }
        public double USD { get; set; }
        public DateTime DT { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
        public List<Item> Items { get; set; } = new List<Item>();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you name your tables and fields the same as the class and property names, it should just work.

Comment: I do it, but it's doesnt help. For the sake of this, I even removed PartnerBalance so that there was only one balance with the same name, but still. Tables, classes, fields, I renamed them all.

Comment: Are you doing [all of this](https://entity-framework.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/9280/entity-framework-with-sqlite)?

Comment: Yes, I used this as setup guide.

Comment: Why do you do `using(ContextClass CC = new ContextClass()){...}` ? In creating a ContextClass you are creating a new ContextClass.   Just `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE TABLE....");` should do (i think, but i am pretty new to this subject )

Comment: It makes sense, thanks, but my question is different

Comment: @Crowley: OK, my bad, i stopped reading after "But how to correctly create them manually so that .Net understands them and loads them correctly?"